# Optimal page replacement algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am writing a program that does 3 page replacement algorithms. FIFO, LRU, and OPT
I am assuming "demand" paging here.

I have FIFO, and LRU finished. But i have no idea on how to tackle OPT. 
I prompting for a file that i am reading in and parsing line by line into pid and a ref number thats in a class. I am also prompting for the frame size.

File is structured like this:

```
1 45  // 1= pid,  45 = ref
1 46
1 45
```

For the LRU i used a second array to keep track of the least recently used slot with a counter.

I am just not sure what to do for opt. Do i need to look ahead in file i am parsing?
Do i need a second array?

I am parsing the file line by line and adding it to the class as follows. This is what i did for the other 2 algorithms and will need to parse the file line by line and prompt for frame size. I could store the file in an array and process the array i guess.

```
class pagetable
{

public:
int pid;
int ref;
int faults;
pagetable();
};
```

and in main()

```
ifstream inputStream;
cout << "\n\n\t*********** Virtual Memory Management Simulator ***********\n";
cout << "\n";


while(!done){
 pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];

getFileName(inputStream);//asks for input filename until it is valid
   cout << "\nEnter in the number of frames:";
cin >> frames;
   faults = runsimLFU2(inputStream, page, frames );

int runsimLFU2(ifstream &inputStream, pagetable* page, int frames ){

int i =0;
int j=0;
int pid =0;
int ref = 0;
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
int pagefaults = 0;
int lowest=0;

int counter = 1;

int * LRU;
LRU = new int[frames];


while(1){

  inputStream >> pid;  //parse the file line by line
  inputStream >> ref;
      page[index].pid = pid;   //lets add it... when needed
  page[index].ref = ref;
```

im just not sure what to do when if im parsing the file and the cache is full and the number thats in the file is not in the cache how do i know where to put it? Can you explain in coding terms.

Whats the way to go about this in coding it with arrays? Do i keep a counter in a second array?
Can someone please explain the easiest way of doing this?

Keep in mind that the file can be hundreds of lines long.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean by "optimum".  The most optimum replacement algorithm would be omniscient and would know in advance what order future pages will be referenced.

If you're assuming "demand" paging, you'd pick for replacement the the page that will next be referenced the greatest distance in the future.

If you also assume omniscient predictive paging it probably gets more complicated -- I don't know if there's a simple rule or not.

If you don't assume omniscience, then "optimum" would presumably be driven by paging statistics, and you'd pick for replacement the page that was statistically least likely to be referenced in the future.

Comment: I am assuming "demand" paging. How would i go about finding the distance? Do i look ahead in the file to see when the number matches again? Im confused.

Comment: Yeah, basically you'd look ahead in the file and find the page that, of the group of pages that are currently in memory, has its next reference the farthest in the future -- that's the one you replace.  (This, of course, is not something you could do in real life, but it gives you a result that is a bound on the best you could possibly do with a "real" statistics-based scheme.)

Comment: How far do i look in the file? I am parsing the file line by line. inputStream >> pid; like that.. I could parse 4-5 into the file and then check those variables?

Comment: @icelated -- You could have to look all the way to the end (though there are ways to figure out when you've gone far enough).  Or, better, pre-process the file in some way to that the info is at hand when you need it.  Going 4-5 deep might work in "toy" cases but not for a real memory access trace.

Comment: I think i will make a struct seperate from the class and process the entire file into that and then i can process that into my class and i can use that to look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Optimal Page Replacement Full Program in C Language**

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int frame_size, no_of_pages, flag1, flag2, flag3, i, j, k, pos, max, page_faults = 0, hit = 0;
    int pri[20][30], frames[10], pages[30], temp[10];
    char x[20];

    printf("Enter number of pages: ");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_pages);

        printf("Enter the pages: ");
        for(i = 0; i < no_of_pages; ++i)
        {
                scanf("%d", &pages[i]);
        }

        printf("Enter number of frames: ");
    scanf("%d", &frame_size);

        for(i=0; i< no_of_pages; i++)
        {
                x[i]='X';
        }
    for(i = 0; i < frame_size; ++i)
        {
                frames[i] = -1;
    }


    for(i = 0; i < no_of_pages; ++i)
        {
                flag1 = flag2 = 0;

                for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                {
                    if(frames[j] == pages[i])
                        {
                           flag1 = flag2 = 1;
                           x[i]='*';
                           break;
                    }
                }

                if(flag1 == 0)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                        {
                                if(frames[j] == -1)
                                {
                                        page_faults++;
                                        //x[j]='*';
                                frames[j] = pages[i];
                                flag2 = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                }
                }

                if(flag2 == 0)
                {
                    flag3 =0;

                    for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                        {
                                temp[j] = -1;

                                for(k = i + 1; k < no_of_pages; ++k)
                                {
                                    if(frames[j] == pages[k])
                                        {
                                        temp[j] = k;
                                                break;
                                   }
                                }
                    }

                    for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                        {
                                if(temp[j] == -1)
                                {
                                        pos = j;
                                flag3 = 1;
                                break;
                                }
                    }

                    if(flag3 ==0)
                        {
                                max = temp[0];
                                pos = 0;

                                for(j = 1; j < frame_size; ++j)
                                {
                                    if(temp[j] > max)
                                        {
                                                max = temp[j];
                                                pos = j;
                                    }
                                }
                }

                        frames[pos] = pages[i];
                page_faults++;
                }

                for(j = 0; j < frame_size; j++)
                {
                    pri[j][i]=frames[j];
                }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }
//              printf("\n|Frames |");
                        printf("\n|       |");
                for(i=0; i<= 2* no_of_pages + 6; i++)
                {
                        printf(" ");
                }
                printf("Pages");
                for(i=0; i<= 2*no_of_pages + 6; i++)
                {
                        printf(" ");
                }
                printf("|");
printf("\n|Frames |");

                        for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size - 8; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }
                printf("\n|\t|");


        for(i=0 ; i < no_of_pages ; i++)
                {
                        printf(" %2d |",pages[i]);
                }
                printf("\n|");
                for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size + 0; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }
                printf("\n");



    for(i=0;i<frame_size;i++)
    {
        printf("| %2d",i);
        printf("\t|");

                for(j = 0; j < no_of_pages; j++)
                {
                        if(pri[i][j]== -1)
                        {
                                printf("  - |");
                        }
                        else
                    printf(" %2d |",pri[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
        {
                printf("-");
        }

        printf("\n|       |");
                                                                                  for(i = 0; i< no_of_pages; i++)
        {
                if(x[i]=='X')
                {
                        printf("\033[0;31m");
                        printf(" %2c ",x[i]);
                        printf("\033[0m");
                        printf("|");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("\033[0;32m");
                        printf(" %2c ",x[i]);
                        printf("\033[0m");
                        printf("|");
                }
        }
        //printf("\033[0m")
        printf("\n");
        for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
        {
                printf("-");
        }

        hit = no_of_pages-page_faults;


        printf("\n\n Total Page Faults =  Total No of pages - Total Pages hits  \n");
    printf("                   =        %d      -       %d      \n",no_of_pages,hit);
    printf("                   =        %d      \n",page_faults);

        printf("\n Total Page Hits = Total No of pages - Total Pages Miss \n ");
        printf("                =       %d      -       %d      \n",no_of_pages,page_faults);
        printf("                 =      %d      \n",hit);

    printf("\nTotal Page Fault ratio = Total Page faults / Total pages \n");
        printf("                       =        %d      /       %d      \n",page_faults,no_of_pages);
        printf("                       =        %5.2f   \n",((float)page_faults/no_of_pages));

    printf("\nTotal Page Hit ratio = Total Page hits / Total pages \n");
    printf("                     =      %d      /       %d      \n",(no_of_pages-page_faults),no_of_pages);
    printf("                     =      %5.2f   \n",((float)no_of_pages-page_faults)/no_of_pages);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}

**OUTPUT**

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYG6x.png
```